# As an Immediate joiner, is it okay to provide your documents and get offer letters from several companies and maybe reject it afterwards?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-offer, new-job, job-change

**Scenario**: I am an **Indian** and a 5+ years experienced Java developer and currently I have been looking for a job change within **India**. I am an **immediate joiner** and my notice period in previous company got over a week back. So whichever company I am getting selected to is asking me ***to get onboarded within a day or two*** because what they feared is *I am an immediate joiner* and my technical fields are strong and it would not take me much time to get higher offers from other companies and join the other one.

**Problem**: I am waiting for the best company to hire me. But I need an offer letter to negotiate for a higher package, obviously at some point of time package matters even if you are getting the best. I have been selected in 4 companies till now but with no offer letter because it is *pending with me to submit my documents*. 2 of them are startups and 2 of them are mid-level. I ***fear giving my documents to companies where I know I will not be joining*** once I get an offer from a top MNC. And also if I submit my documents ***they will take no time to release the offer letter and get me onboarded the same day*** (since they need resources to build their company) which I don't want since I am waiting for the best and don't wanna get into the confusing stuffs of walking away during probation period or within 1-2 days of joining a company. Even they know what you will do after getting an offer letter.
But I desperately need the offer letters for a better package/negotiation. What should I do ?

Currently I am just trying to hang on with the 4 companies that I have been selected to and telling them stuffs that I need more time to submit my documents because of some reason so that if I don't get offer letters from top MNC early or I don't clear interviews in my dream companies, I might carry on with one of the 4 that I have been selected to previously.

But I need an offer letter from earlier selected companies even to negotiate with my dream company without joining them. How is that possible after being an immediate joiner where I don't get much time to wait?

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you marketed yourself as an immediate joiner. If they need someone to immediately start, stalling tactics are probably not going to work. (Also, you have a few run-on sentences which are hard to read - and I'm a native speaker)

Comment: You should really say that you're in India in your question. Half of what you're talking about doesn't apply to the US or to Europe. So most of the advice we give you probably won't take into account the intricacies of your situation.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I will mention that Immediately. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you phrase your request. Companies will want to know “do you like our offer”? The correct answer is a variation of:

> I am really excited but I would like to have offer letter to make the decision. I need to consult with my family, and discuss all the details of this opportunity.

Whether you need offer letter to solicit competing offers, or other reason, offer letter is the only realistic version of your potential contract. It is absolutely professional to ask for offer letter instead of relying on the verbal offer.

Final note: you consider yourself a strong candidate, so negotiate using this information. Ask for later start dates. Understand that companies are using “we want you to start asap!!!11” as part of their negotiation tactics.

Comment: @Monica, Thanks for your answer. The only question that I am left with is "Is it okay to give your documents to startups/mid-level companies" ? Or may be suppose you got selected in 6 companies and can we share our documents to all 6(startups, mid-level, top MNC) without any fear/hesitation ?

Comment: @lazy_coder unfortunately, we can't predict what company X will do. That being said, it is professional to receive offer letter, and then not accept it.Be careful, as it is unprofessional to verbally accept offer, agree to salary/job description etc, and then reject after getting offer letter.

Answer (score 1):

You communicated "immediate joiner" at the time of interview, and now would like to change the terms that you communicated.
The HR/teams at various companies do understand the power of offer letters, and hence having a job in hand is very useful when negotiating.

Also, even if you had said "immediate joiner", you can still ask for a formal offer letter to review the terms and conditions of employment, salary offered, etc.

What harm do you anticipate from handing over (copies) of your document? If you need to hand over originals that would definitely need more thinking over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Starlight. I mean I myself am not sure if there is any harm as such. Just worried like my personal/critical business details are spreading and for instance if PAN card/authentication proof, which if falls into wrong hands can lead you into problems.

Comment: @lazy_coder if you want the offer letter, you will need to hand over documents (assuming those are company rules). It's a fair trade-off for you, isn;t it?

Comment: Very true @Starlight. So you are saying there's nothing to worry, your documents are perfectly safe inside an organization even if it is just for a sake of an offer letter ?

Comment: @lazy_coder I can't say they are perfectly safe. Nor can anyone. I did say it is a fair trade-off. You get the offer letter, for handing over copies of your documents.

Comment: Okay @Starlight. Thanks for your answer!